# Standard ML: Ugly isLeapYear Function

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I'm trying to write a function in Standard ML using `case of` but I end up with code that screams for a bunch of `if / else`'s.  Is this just a poor candidate for using `case of` or is there a better way of setting this up so I'm not constantly mapping booleans to booleans?

Here's my code:

```
fun isLeapYear(y) =
    case (y mod 400 = 0) of
        true => true |
        false => (case ((y mod 100 = 0)) of
            true => false |
            false => (case (y mod 4 = 0) of
                true => true |
                false => false));
```

Thanks for the help,
bclayman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't care about a few extra instructions:

```
fun isLeapYear(y) = case (y mod 400, y mod 100, y mod 4) of
    (0, _, _) => true 
  | (_, 0, _) => false
  | (_, _, 0) => true
  | (_, _, _) => false
```

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, `case X of true => E1 | false => E2`" directly corresponds to `if X then E1 else E2`, which I personally would prefer. (After all, `if ... then ... else ...` is kind of a specialized case construct, which only works on booleans, right?) Turning it into that gives us:

```
fun isLeapYear(y) =
          if y mod 400 = 0 then true
     else if y mod 100 = 0 then false
     else if y mod   4 = 0 then true
     else                       false
```

Which brings me to the second point: You can always rewrite an `if B then E1 else E2`, where one of the `E`s is `true` or `false`, using the following table:

[image: Table of how to rewrite if statements containing bools]

(Pardon the Danish headings, it's taken from the book "[IP-2: Supplerende noter i Introduktion til programmering](http://www.fys.ku.dk/~arvid/FP-2.pdf)", which we use for teaching SML at University of Copenhagen.)

Anyhow, rewriting using this, we get:

```
fun isLeapYear(y) =
              if y mod 400 = 0 then true
         else if y mod 100 = 0 then false
         else if y mod   4 = 0 then true
         else                       false
```

becomes

```
fun isLeapYear(y) =
              if y mod 400 = 0 then true
         else if y mod 100 = 0 then false
         else                       y mod   4 = 0
```

becomes

```
fun isLeapYear(y) =
              if y mod 400 = 0 then true
                               else not (y mod 100 = 0) andalso y mod 4 = 0
```

becomes

```
fun isLeapYear(y) = y mod 400 = 0 orelse (not (y mod 100 = 0) andalso y mod 4 = 0)
```

Finally we can turn the `not (y mod 100 = 0)` into `y mod 100 <> 0`, giving:

```
fun isLeapYear(y) = y mod 400 = 0 orelse (y mod 100 <> 0 andalso y mod 4 = 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

In general whenever you see

```ml
case p of
  true => true
  | false => q
```

(or equivalently `if p then true else q`) you should write

```ml
p orelse q
```

Likewise

```ml
case p of
  false => false
  true => q
```

is just `p andalso q`

Finally

```
case p of
  true => true
  false => false
```

is just `p`.

So your example is better written as

```ml
y mod 400 = 0
orelse (y mod 100 <> 0
        andalso y mod 4 = 0)
```